# Adding __getattribute__ to print message for type string

Tags: python, string, getattribute

I am trying to add printing/logging a **message every time certain variable is accessed**(in if, for, print, assigned to another variable), these are always string.

What is working( But not exactly what I need, below if statement I do not want to access it as **e.t**, rather I want to access it as **e**):

```
class A(object):
    def __inti__(self, string):
        self.string = string
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print("message")
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
e = A('test')
e.t = 'test'
if e.t == 'test':
    print('test')
print(e)
```

Output:

```
message
test
<__main__.A object at 0x2af4fafa52d0>
```

Changing object to str:

```
class A(str):
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print(f"message")
        return str.__getattribute__(self, name)
    #def __repr__(self):
    #    print("message")
    #    return self.string
    pass

e = A('test')
if e == 'test':
    print('test')
print(e)
```

Output(Not printing message):

```
test
test
```

**The output I am looking for above example in stdout is**:

```
message <some other init variables> 
<Value of string>
```

Also the behaviour to evaluate if statement in string context this is the time it prints out message...

General questions:
Let say

```
if a: print(True)
```

What magic function does python call to run if a? Is it **getattribute**?
For python str class is it not possible to override **getattribute**?

Thanks

Comment: You should overwrite other methods like `__eq__()` or `__bool__()`. Otherwise, they'll call the same methods of the super class, which will call the original `__getattribute__()` instead of your overwritten one.

Comment: I want the new class(str) object to have all capabilities of string and still print the message while accessing. So do I have to implement all functions that I get by ```dir(str)``` in new class? ```dir(str)``` returns 78 functions